# Estimates for square free integers

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I want to estimate $\sum \limits_{n\leq x} \mu^2(n)$ with error term $o(\sqrt{x})$ Given that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{\psi(x)}{x}=1$ or that $\lim \limits_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{x} \sum\limits_{n\leq x} \mu(x) = 0$

Without PNT i managed to estimate it with error term $O(\sqrt{x})$

My attempt : $\sum \limits_{n\leq x} \mu^2(n) = \sum \limits_{d^2 \leq x} \mu(d) [\frac{x}{d^2}] =  x \sum \limits_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} + O( |\sum \limits_{n\leq \sqrt{x}} \mu(n)|)  $ and since $M_{\mu} (\sqrt{x}) = o(\sqrt{x})$ it follows that $O( |\sum \limits_{n\leq \sqrt{x}} \mu(n)|)=o(\sqrt{x})$ ,but i don't know how to get error term $o(\sqrt{x})$ form $ x \sum \limits_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} = \frac{6x}{\pi^2} - x \sum \limits_{d > \sqrt{x}} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} $

Comment: Wikipedia only has one unconditional result for the error that's $o\left(\sqrt x\right)$, from Arnold Walfisz, 1963, "Weylsche Exponentialsummen in der neueren Zahlentheorie":

$$
O\left(x^{1/2}\exp\left(-c\frac{(\log x)^{3/5}}{(\log\log x)^{1/5}}\right)\right)\;,
$$

with $c$ a positive constant. The book is available online. It's in German. The proof extends over $4$ pages. If you don't speak German, I could summarize it for you in an answer.

Comment: Your proof is wrong; $$\sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} \mu(d) \left\lfloor \frac{x}{d^2}\right\rfloor = x \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} \frac{\mu}{d^2} + \sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} \mu(d) \left( \left\lfloor \frac{x}{d^2}\right\rfloor - \frac{x}{d^2}\right).$$ The correct trivial bound on the latter is $O(\sum_{d \leq \sqrt{x}} |\mu(d)|)$, which unfortunately can only be bounded by $O(\sqrt{x})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\bigl\lfloor \frac{x}{d^2}\bigr\rfloor = 0$ for $d > \sqrt{x}$ we can extend the sum giving $Q(x)$ to infinity,
$$Q(x) = \sum_{d = 1}^{\infty} \mu(d)\biggl\lfloor \frac{x}{d^2}\biggr\rfloor = x\sum_{d = 1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(d)}{d^2} - \sum_{d = 1}^{\infty} \mu(d) \biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{d^2}\biggr\rbrace\,,\tag{1}$$
where $\{u\} = u - \lfloor u\rfloor$ denotes the fractional part.

The first term on the right of $(1)$ is exactly $\frac{6}{\pi^2}\cdot x$, so what we need is to show
$$\sum_{d = 1}^{\infty} \mu(d) \biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{d^2}\biggr\rbrace = o(\sqrt{x})\,.\tag{2}$$
Now the trick is to split the series at a suitable $y < \sqrt{x}$ (where $y$ depends on $x$ of course). For the first part we use the trivial estimate,
$$\sum_{d = 1}^{y} \mu(d) \biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{d^2}\biggr\rbrace = O(y)$$
since $\lvert\mu(d)\rvert$ and fractional parts are bounded by $1$. Thus we must choose $y = o(\sqrt{x})$. The choice $y = \bigl\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{x}{m(x)}}\bigr\rfloor$ where the positive integer $m(x)$ tends to $\infty$ slowly as $x \to \infty$ is convenient.

To estimate the tail series, write $\mu(d) = M(d) - M(d-1)$ and apply summation by parts. If we have a strong enough bound for $M(x)$, we can see that $\sum \lvert M(d+c)\rvert\bigl\lbrace\frac{x}{d^2}\bigr\rbrace$ converges for every constant $c \geqslant 0$, so we can simply split and recombine the series. But with only $M(x) = o(x)$ available, a more cautious summation by parts is needed. For $z > y$ we have
\begin{align}
\sum_{d = y+1}^{z} \bigl(M(d) - M(d-1)\bigr)\biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{d^2}\biggr\rbrace
&= M(z)\biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{(z+1)^2}\biggr\rbrace - M(y)\biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{(y+1)^2}\biggr\rbrace \\
&\qquad + \sum_{d = y+1}^{z} M(d)\biggl(\biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{d^2} \biggr\rbrace - \biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{(d+1)^2}\biggr\rbrace \biggr)\,.
\end{align}
The first term on the right tends to $0$ as $z \to \infty$. In the sum on the right hand side,
$$\biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{d^2} \biggr\rbrace - \biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{(d+1)^2}\biggr\rbrace = \frac{x(2d+1)}{d^2(d+1)^2} - \underbrace{\biggl(\biggl\lfloor \frac{x}{d^2} \biggr\rfloor - \biggl\lfloor \frac{x}{(d+1)^2}\biggr\rfloor\biggr)}_{s(x,d)}\,,$$
where $s(x,d) = 0$, unless there is a positive integer $k$ such that $d = \bigl\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{x}{k}}\bigr\rfloor$, in which case it is $1$ if we choose $y$ not too small, $y > \sqrt[3]{3x}$, roughly equivalent to $m(x) < \sqrt[3]{\frac{x}{9}}$, suffices easily. Thus we can take the limit for $z \to \infty$ and obtain
$$\sum_{d = y+1}^{\infty} \mu(d)\biggl\lbrace \frac{x}{d^2}\biggr\rbrace
= -\sum_{k = 1}^{m(x)-1} M\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{x}{k}}\biggr) - M(y)\biggl\lbrace\frac{x}{(y+1)^2}\biggr\rbrace + \sum_{d = y+1}^{\infty} \frac{xM(d)(2d+1)}{d^2(d+1)^2}\,.$$
With
$$\delta(u) := \sup \: \bigl\{ x^{-1}\lvert M(x)\rvert : x \geqslant u\bigr\}$$
we can then estimate
$$\Biggl\lvert\sum_{k = 1}^{m(x)-1} M\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{x}{k}}\biggr)\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \delta(y)\sqrt{x}\sum_{k = 1}^{m(x)-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \leqslant \delta(y)\sqrt{x}(2\sqrt{m(x)}+1)\,,$$
$\bigl\lvert M(y)\bigl\lbrace\frac{x}{(y+1)^2}\bigr\rbrace\bigr\rvert \leqslant y$ trivially, and
$$\Biggl\lvert \sum_{d = y+1}^{\infty} \frac{xM(d)(2d+1)}{d^2(d+1)^2} \Biggr\rvert
\leqslant 2\delta(y)x \sum_{d = y+1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{d(d+1)} < 2\delta(y)\sqrt{x}\cdot \sqrt{m(x)}\,.$$
Thus to prove the $o(\sqrt{x})$ error term we need to choose $m(x)$ (tending to $\infty$ with $x$) in such a way that
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{m(x)}\delta\biggl(\biggl\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{x}{m(x)}}\biggr\rfloor\biggr) = 0\,.$$
We can do that: Choose a strictly increasing sequence $(\eta_k)$ in $[1,+\infty)$ such that $\delta(\eta_k) \leqslant \frac{1}{k}$. Put $\xi_k = k(\eta_k + 1)^2$ and $m(x) = k$ for $\xi_k \leqslant x < \xi_{k+1}$ (and $m(x) = 1$ for $x < \xi_1$). Clearly $m(x) \to \infty$ for $x\to \infty$, and for $\xi_k \leqslant x < \xi_{k+1}$ we have, using the monotonicity of $\delta$,
\begin{align}
\sqrt{m(x)}\delta\biggl(\biggl\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{x}{m(x)}}\biggr\rfloor\biggr)
&= \sqrt{k}\delta\biggl(\biggl\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{x}{k}}\biggr\rfloor\biggr) \\
&\leqslant \sqrt{k}\delta\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{x}{k}}-1\biggr) \\
&\leqslant \sqrt{k} \delta\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{\xi_k}{k}} - 1\biggr) \\
&= \sqrt{k} \delta\bigl(\sqrt{(\eta_k+1)^2} - 1\bigr) \\
&= \sqrt{k}\delta(\eta_k) \\
&\leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}}\,.
\end{align}

With explicit bounds for $\delta$ one can obtain explicit bounds for the error term. If we have a bound of the type
$$\delta(x) = O\bigl(\exp\bigl(-c(\log x)^{\alpha}\bigr)\bigr)$$
with $c > 0$ and $0 <\alpha < 1$ — the exponent $\alpha = \frac{1}{2}$ corresponds to de la Vallée Poussin's zero-free region from 1899, the error term of Walfisz (not quite the same form, but similar enough) corresponds to that of Vinogradov/Korobov from 1958 — we can choose
$$m(x) \approx \exp\bigl(b(\log x)^{\alpha}\bigr)$$
with an appropriate $0 < b < c$. Then $y = O\bigl(\sqrt{x}\,\exp(-b/2(\log x)^{\alpha})\bigr)$, and
$$\log \sqrt{\frac{x}{m(x)}} \sim \frac{1}{2}\log x\biggl(1 - \frac{b}{(\log x)^{1-\alpha}}\biggr) \sim \frac{1}{2}\log x\,.$$
For every $0 < c' < c$ we therefore have
$$\sqrt{m(x)}\delta\biggl(\biggl\lfloor \sqrt{\frac{x}{m(x)}}\biggr\rfloor\biggr) = O\biggl(\exp\biggl(-\biggl(\frac{c'}{2^{\alpha}} - \frac{b}{2}\biggr)(\log x)^{\alpha}\biggr)\biggr)\,.$$
The choice $b = c'\cdot 2^{-\alpha}$ yields
$$Q(x) = \frac{6}{\pi^2}x + O\bigl(\sqrt{x}\,\exp\bigl(-b/2(\log x)^{\alpha}\bigr)\bigr)\,.$$

If we have a considerably stronger bound for $\delta$, say $\delta(x) = O(x^{-\beta})$ (meaning $\zeta(s)$ has no zeros with real part  $> 1-\beta$), the loss in the strength of the error term becomes more obvious. We get the best order if we choose $m(x)$ such that
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{m(x)}} \asymp \sqrt{m(x)}\delta\biggl(\sqrt{\frac{x}{m(x)}}\biggr)$$
(that's also the case for bounds of the previous type), which occurs for
$$m(x) \asymp x^{\beta/(2+\beta)}$$
and leads to an error bound of $O(x^{1/(2+\beta)})$ rather than the $\frac{1-\beta}{2}$ exponent one might hope for because $\zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)$ has no poles except at $1$ with real part $> \frac{1-\beta}{2}$.